# Get receive keyboard an mouse events from SDL2 in WPF application

Tags: wpf, multithreading, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to capture mouse and keyboard events from SDL2 using the [SDL2-CS](https://github.com/flibitijibibo/SDL2-CS/) binding library. The events are polled for but these events are never raised.

I think this is because the polling needs to happen on the UI thread. I tried initializing SDL from the UI thread by calling `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Init)` but no events are polled.

Basic implementation of my class:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    if (hooked)
    {
        return;
    }

    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Init); //Run on the UI thread        
}

private void Init()
{
    var init = SDL.SDL_Init(SDL.SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    if (init != 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not initialize SDL");
    }
    hooked = true;
    ListenForEvents();

}

private void ListenForEvents()
{
    SDL.SDL_Event ev;
    while (true)
    {
        if (SDL.SDL_PollEvent(out ev) != 1) //This is continuously trigged
        {
            continue;
        }

        switch (ev.type) //This is never reached
        {
            case SDL.SDL_EventType.SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                if (MouseMoved != null) { MouseMoved(this, ev.motion); }
                break;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondring if I'm invoking the `Init` on the UI thread wrong, or if the SDL initialization is wrong.

P.S. Hooking with user32.dll is not desired because this code will run on non windows environments as well.

Comment: Looks like this cannot be done without a window. I need all events, even those outside the window. I've tried setting the SdL_VIDEODRIVER to dummy, this hides the window. But then no more events are received.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I would say your UI is blocked because ListenForEvents is not running on a different thread and invoking the Init call will run the method - that never returns - on the UI thread.

It might be a good idea to call Init invoked, but then you should start a new thread for polling.

Comment: I've tried `Init` on the UI thread and `ListeningForEvents` on a background thread as follows: `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(Init);
Task.Run(() => ListenForEvents()); ` But this does not seem to work. The `Initialize` method does not block. and the loops keep running, but no events are polled.